# ANTLR4 AST vistor and node return Type: should I have more than one visitor?

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to learn ANTLR (using v4), and I'm using visitors to walk the AST that antlr generates.

to help me learn - I've come up with a silly language to parse. it has lists of 'senators'

`FirstName LastName (party)` e.g `BA Baracus (R)`

These populate a universe (in an `ArrayList()`) that you can do things with later on

... and also some 'actions' like

`~printRhouse` to print out the house of representatives (i.e print out the universe, grouped by party)

ANTLR generates me a base visitor which is a paramaterized class - so I have subclassed with a Class supplied as `T` - this class seems to them be what all the methods in the visitor return.

Antlr generates something like

```
public class SenatorBaseVisitor<T> extends AbstractParseTreeVisitor<T> implements SenatorVisitor<T> {
```

which I then came up with a concrete implementation of like this.

```
public class InitialParseVisitor extends SenatorBaseVisitor<SenatorASTContainer> {
```

I've found myself writing a 'container' class (`SenatorASTContainer` in this case) than can capture anything that the tree methods can return - in this case statements defining new senators, or 'actions' like 'printhouse'. This feels bad because this class becomes very cluttered and multi-function as it has to deal with every type of node in the tree.

Am I thinking about this the wrong way? - should I have n walkers, each with a much more single-purpose return type, and all designed to do one thing. Each of these would ignore the nodes that are of a different type by choosing not to visit them.

One would then walk the AST n times, each with a different walker that sniffs for different things, finally putting together the final program from the output of the multiple runs.

If not, and one walker type is normally sufficient, then how should I think about the return type of the methods when I have nodes of different types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having multiple visitors does not solve the problem: Effectively every rule with non trivial syntax will get its own visitor (and result node). The resulting code would be hardly maintainable.

I think the most common approach is to use `SenatorASTContainer` as super class to all generated AST nodes:

`FirstName`, `LastName`, `Party` would be probably `StringNode extends SenatorASTContainer` and one line would be of type `Senator extends SenatorASTContainer`. Yet the visitor for `Senator` will have to cast the results of lower nodes to `StringNode` (the visitor will only return generic `SenatorASTContainer`).

Comment: Coming from a combinatory parser (Sprache) this is the issue that has been most difficult so far to get my head around. Allowing one to specify a type for every production rule, and then the transformation (from production rule's items into the desired return type) make the code quite clean. Too bad there isn't a way to marry that idea with the other great features of ANTLR4.

Answer (score 4):

Relevant to your question, Antlr supports at least two primary visitor strategies: (1) the return class used essentially as an accumulator and (2) annotation of the parse tree with node type specific property classes.

For the annotation strategy, extend [ParseTreeProperty](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTreeProperty.java) to create context node type specific property classes.  See the comment in that class for how to use.

Typically, walk the parse tree one or more times to create, analyze, and modify the property data. Walk a final time to generate output. Here is an [example project](https://github.com/GRosenberg/GenProjectModel) using the annotation strategy approach.

Where the return class strategy tends to heavily overuse a single class, the annotation strategy tends to a proliferation of smallish classes with a fair bit of boilerplate.  Here is a [code generator](https://github.com/GRosenberg/GenPackage) that may help with this 'problem.'